# Facebook login for private group members

Tags: login, facebook, members

How can I make 'Facebook login' on my website to only allow members of a closed Facebook group to login?
There are many Facebook login plugins and php codes available to allow anyone to login but none seem to specialise in only closed group members.
Any help would be appreciated.